# JWT signature not verifying in PHP

Tags: php, security, authentication, token, jwt

I'm just getting started with token-based authentication and have written a very simple PHP script to create a JWT. However, when I run it in jwt.io's debugger, the signature never verifies.

[JWT.io](https://jwt.io/)

```
    $secret = "super_secure_private_key";

    function base64url_encode($data) {
        return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($data), "+/", "-_"), "=");
    }

    $header = base64url_encode(json_encode([
        "alg" => "HS256",
        "typ" => "JWT"
    ]));

    $payload = base64url_encode(json_encode([
        "name" => "James Walker",
        "privileges" => "total"
    ]));

    $signature = base64url_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", $header . "." . $payload, $secret));

    $token = $header . "." . $payload . "." . $signature;
```

As far as I can tell, my implementation is inline with the formatting of JWT. Have I missed something, or should I use a library e.g. php-jwt to generate new tokens and get them verified?

For my use, my implementation would probably work alright anyway, since I can still verify the tokens myself using the same code. But I'm just not sure why jwt.io isn't verifying the signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue gave me a big headache when I first wrote my JWT implementation. The trick is that the keyed hash that creates the signature must output raw binary data, but the default setting of `hash_hmac` is not that.

Change how you generate your signature from:

```
hash_hmac("sha256", $header . "." . $payload, $secret);
```

To

```
hash_hmac("sha256", $header . "." . $payload, $secret, true);
```

See info about the last parameter [in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php):

> raw_output: When set to TRUE, outputs raw binary data. FALSE outputs
>   lowercase hexits

Comment: Thank you so much! It works now and all my signatures verify. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Ilmiont happy coding *<tip of the hat>*